# MYSQL Query exported to .csv error

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

i have tried to export mysql Query into CSV file with the command bellow :

```
SELECT g.id, g.name, g.date, g.date_mod, g.status, cree_par, modifier_par
FROM glpi_tickets g , (select id, concat(realname , ' ' , firstname)
cree_par from glpi_users ) c, (select id, concat(realname , ' ' ,
firstname) modifier_par from glpi_users) m
where users_id_recipient <> users_id_lastupdater
and users_id_recipient = c.id
and users_id_lastupdater = m.id 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/orders.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

and i got this error msg in mysql :

```
#1 - Can't create/write to file '\tmp\orders.csv' (Errcode: 2)
```

i have tried to modify the .htaccess file in the xampp\tmp folder

from :

```
SetHandler Drupal_Security_Do_Not_Remove_See_SA_2006_006 Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

into :

> Allow from all

but still facing the same error msg

Comment: Does the directory exist?

Comment: And is it writeable for the user who is running the query?